# How does the FF symbol get in an html page?

Tags: html, unicode

I am reviewing some old html pages and am finding these FF symbols inline in my Sublime editor. Specifically, in the dark background mode of the editor, you can see FF with a light background rectangle having rounded corners.

When I paste the page into the textarea of https://validator.w3.org/, the result is, "Warning This document is not mappable to XML 1.0 without data loss due to U+000c which is not a legal XML 1.0 character." It points to the line in which the FF symbol appears. I merely backspace over it to get rid of it and then it validates fine.

I looked up the U+000C and found it is a character for form feed.

How did this character appear on my pages? I don't recall it ever being something I would add in my early html days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF is a "Form Feed" character, which can sometimes get inserted by various text editors as a "page break."